# Is This Matrix Diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider the matrix A below:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$

Is the matrix A diagonalizable? If so, then find a diagonal matrix D and an invertible matrix P such that $P^{-1}AP=D$.

I know it is supposed to be diagonalizable but I have tried to solve it and haven't succeeded. The format I'm used to is $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the eigenvalues?

Comment: Where you got stuck? You may add more details about your failure so we can help you. :)

Comment: Yeah I will do it again now. I wanted to make sure that is where I am not going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some regular computations for eigenvalues and eigenvectors you should find

$$\matrix{
   {{\lambda _1} = 2} \hfill &  \to  \hfill & {{X_1} = \left[ {\matrix{
   { - 2}  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   1  \cr 
 } } \right]} \hfill & {{X_2} = \left[ {\matrix{
   { - 2}  \cr 
   1  \cr 
   0  \cr 
 } } \right]} \hfill  \cr 
   {{\lambda _2} = 3} \hfill &  \to  \hfill & {{X_3} = \left[ {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   { - 1}  \cr 
   1  \cr 
 } } \right]} \hfill & {} \hfill  \cr
 } $$

and hence your matrix $P$ will be

$$P = \left[ {\matrix{
   {{X_1}} & {{X_2}} & {{X_3}}  \cr 
 } } \right] = \left[ {\matrix{
   \hfill { - 2} & \hfill { - 2} & \hfill 1 \cr 
   \hfill 0 & \hfill 1 & \hfill { - 1} \cr 
   \hfill 1 & \hfill 0 & \hfill 1 \cr 
 } } \right]$$

and finally

$$D = {P^{ - 1}}AP = \left[ {\matrix{
   2 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 2 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 3  \cr 
 } } \right]$$

will be the diagonal matrix where its diagonal elements are the eigenvalues. However, as $\lambda_1=2$ had multiplicity $2$, it will appear twice on the diagonal here! :)

Comment: So it is diagonalizable? Also, did you just put the eigenvalues on the diagonal  with zeros everywhere else just because you knew that's the correct answer or would you get the same answer if you did each matrix multiplied by each other? Referring to the $P^{-1}AP=D$. Thanks.

Comment: @juliodesa: Yes, as you could find three linearly independent **eigen-vectors**. :)

Comment: Also, did you just put the eigenvalues on the diagonal with zeros everywhere else just because you knew that's the correct answer or would you get the same answer if you did each matrix multiplied by each other? Referring to the $P^{−1}AP=D$. Thanks.

Comment: @juliodesa: You can do the matrix multiplication and you will see that it will happen! :) I did it by MAPLE and it happaned! :) I do suggest to read the proof that why such a thing happens! It is not that much complicated! :)

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial $p(X)=\det(A-XI_3)$ is
$$
p(X)=12-16X+7X^2-X^3=(3-X)(2-X)^2
$$
Now, can you check the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $2$?

> The rank of $A-2I_3$ is $1$, so the geometric multiplicity is $3-1=2$. So yes, the matrix is diagonalizable. Find a basis for the eigenspace relative to $3$ and a basis for the eigenspace relative to $2$ and you've found the diagonalizing matrix.

Comment: $3-1=1$ (in the spoiler)?

Comment: @Keba Typo! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $A$ diagonalizable if $P_A(\lambda)$ has $n$ distinct real roots or if, for each eigenvalue, the algebraic multiplicity equals the geometric multiplicity. So let's find out:

$$P_A(\lambda) = det(A - \lambda I) = det \begin{pmatrix} 3-\lambda & 2 & 2 \\ -1 & -\lambda & -2 \\ 1 & 2 & 4-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ = (3-\lambda)((-\lambda)(4-\lambda) + 4) - 2(\lambda - 4 + 2) + 2(-2+\lambda) = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow -\lambda^3+7 \lambda^2-16 \lambda+12 = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow -(\lambda-3) (\lambda-2)^2 = 0$$
$$\lambda = 3 \text{ (multiplicity $1$)}$$
$$\lambda = 2 \text{ (multiplicity $2$)}$$

We see that $\lambda=2$ has algebraic multiplicity 2, so we need to check for its geometric multiplicity.

Geometric multiplicity is equal to $n - Rank(A - \lambda I)$
$$Rank(A - 2I) = dim\left(col\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\ -1 & -2 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\right) $$
$$ = dim\left(col\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right)  = 1$$

So $$\text{geometric multiplicity}  = 3 - Rank(A - 2I) = 3 - 1 = 2$$
$$ = \text{algebraic multiplicity when $\lambda=2$}$$

**So the matrix *is* diaginalizable.**

Now we can diaginalize it:

Let's find our eigenvectors.
For $\lambda=2$:
$$\vec{V_1} + \vec{V_2} = null(A - \lambda I) = null(A - 2I) = null\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\ -1 & -2 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ = null\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}x_1 + \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}x_2$$
So our eigenpairs so far are $\left(2, \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(2, \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right)$

Now, to find it for $\lambda=3$:
$$\vec{V} = null(A-\lambda I) = null(A - 3I) = null\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 2 \\ -1 & -3 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ = null\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}x_3$$
So our eigenpair is $\left(3, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)$

We now have everything we need to make our diaginalized matrix:

$$PDP^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-2 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
$$ = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 2 \\ -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is incorrect, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=2$ turns out to be $2$ here.

Comment: Good point. Fixed.